# Extracting Seasons in list of Dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, extract, lubridate

I have a list of dataframes, e.g.

```
library(lubridate)
df1 = data.frame (Date = seq(ymd('2005-04-16'),ymd('2016-10-15'),by='day'), 
                  Station1423 = replicate(1,sample(0:130, 4201,rep=TRUE)))
df2 = data.frame (Date = seq(ymd('2001-09-02'),ymd('2018-12-31'),by='day'), 
                  Station4322 = replicate(1,sample(0:130, 6330,rep=TRUE)))
df3 = data.frame (Date = seq(ymd('1995-02-20'),ymd('2018-12-31'),by='day'), 
                  Station1242 = replicate(1,sample(0:130, 8716,rep=TRUE)))

dflist = list(df1, df2, df3)
names(dflist) = c("df1", "df2", "df3")
```

I want to extract now the seasons for each dataframe in the list. The result should be a nested list like this:

```
dflist    list of 3
   df1       list of 4
     DJF: dataframe
     ..$Date
     ..$Station1423   
     JJA: dataframe
     ..$Date
     ..$Station1423   
     MAM: dataframe
     ..$Date
     ..$Station1423 
     SON: dataframe
     ..$Date
     ..$Station1423     
 df2       list of 4
     DJF: dataframe
     ..$Date
     ..$Station4322   
     JJA: dataframe
     ..$Date
     ..$Station4322   
.....and so on
```

Also I would be ok with a simple list like this:

```
dflist    list of 12
  df1_DJF: dataframe
      ..$Date
      ..$Station1423 
  df1_JJA: dataframe
......
```

Comment: And where did your attempt fail?

Comment: I dont know how to do this in a loop. I usually use datelist = dflist$df1$Date and then datelist [which(month(datelist ) %in% c(12,1,2))] and then ddf1_Station1423  = dflist$df1[dflist$df1$Date %in% date_LfU_DJF,]

Comment: What do you mean by extract the seasons exactly?

Comment: I want to do 4 subsets with the seasons...so extracting the dates that belong to one season...for example winter would be December, January, February...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a data frame coding the seasons to a month.

```
seasons <- tibble(month = 1:12, season = c(rep("DJF", 2), rep("MAM", 3), rep("JJA", 3), rep("SON", 3), "DJF"))
```

Use `map` to join to each data frame by month, and then `split` on the season.

```
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

new_list <- dflist %>%
  map( ~ {mutate(., month = month(Date)) %>%
      left_join(seasons, by = "month") %>%
      split(f = .$season)
  })
```

Note that this added two columns to the original data frames. We can remove those pretty easily again with map.

```
new_list %>%
  map_depth(.depth = 2, ~ select(., -month, - season))
```

Or nest another `map` in the original.

```
new_list <- dflist %>%
  map( ~ {mutate(., month = month(Date)) %>%
      left_join(seasons, by = "month") %>%
      split(f = .$season) %>%
      map(~ select(., -month, -season))
  })
```